# Form key validator not working on custom phtml file?

Tags: magento2

For wishlist I created custom phtml file. When added product on logged in customer then it calls function i.e `wishlist/index/add` which is in

> vendor\magento\module-wishlist\Controller\Index\Add.php

Below is not working

```
if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/');
}
```

If I comment then I get the output.

I tried, in custom file I put

```
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
  $FormKey = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey');

<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $FormKey->getFormKey();?>">
```

Comment: what is $FormKey object?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya - I have added $FormKey value in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, simply use: (put it inside your form)

```
<form ......>
......
<?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
......
</form>
```

And your block should be extended from `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will try and let u know by tomorrow

Comment: @jassi put the form key inside the `<form> </form>`

Comment: @jassi, Is that worked?

Comment: @KowsiganAtsayam does it work for your case?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I already added this <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $block->getFormKey() ?>" /> inside form in phtml. But still I am seeing the invalid form key please refresh page error often. Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Is your page cached? I think the page was cached, and it could cause the invalid form key.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh In admin panel it shows ->One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated: Configuration, Page Cache. Please go to Cache Management and refresh cache types. Is I need to clear the cache?